# How to connect AllenNLP model to Microsoft Web Chat or Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: api, botframework, web-chat, allennlp

I need to connect AllenNLP model to Microsoft Web Chat or Microsoft Bot Framework. Is it possible?

is AllenNLP provides any APIs endpoints for connecting?

How do I create models and where that models are store in AllenNLP?

If anyone has a good amount of knowledge, please let me know your feedback on the above questions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about Microsoft Web Chat or Microsoft Bot Framework, but it sounds to me like you'll want to spin up a server serving the model (maybe using https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-server), and then connect to it from your C# code.

Comment: Hi Drik, I have configured Azure Linux VM for the python code hosting and used Django framework for serve. It takes 30-50 seconds to give response using ELMo-BiDAF. You have any idea how can i minimize response time using ELMo-BiDAF model.

Comment: It will run much faster if you have a GPU.

Comment: Hello Dirk, I am using DJango framework and I have tried with GPU but it takes minimum 15 seconds for large passage. I have tested on https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension/bidaf-elmo with my passage and question first time it takes around 26 seconds then it gives response in milliseconds so can you guide me how can i achieve same performance as in AllenNLP demo link?

Comment: http://demo.allennlp.org uses a cache, so when you put in the sequence a second time, it will read from the cache. But also, the demo does not use GPUs. It should be less than 3 seconds on GPU, once the model is loaded. Are you sure your code is using the GPU?

Comment: I used https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension/bidaf-elmo which is in Model Usage using predictor.predict() method.